# How do you automatically indent code for SO?

Tags: discussion

Whenever I ask a coding question, sometimes it might be needed to post a large amount of code.  How can I mass edit the code to include the four spaces before each line of code without doing it manually?

Comment: paste, select, press the `code sample` button, done.

Comment: THANK YOU.  I have been manually pressing spacebar dozens of times :P

Comment: You know, if you'd have google'd _"How do you automatically indent code for SO?"_, you would have gotten the same link...

Comment: You should **never** have a need to do this.  Always copy/paste code from your text editor so you'll have a reasonable guarantee that the code is valid.  You then only ever have to figure out how to *remove* indents.  Same way.

Answer (score 4):

You can utilize the `Code Sample` button, after selecting the text you want to indent, in the editor. It looks like this:

[image: Code Sample Button]

You can also select the text you wish to indent and press the short cut for Code Sample:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>

Comment: Note that you have to select the code before using the `Code Sample` button.